# Iron Python: Next Button Winforms Picturebox

Tags: c#, winforms, ironpython

I'm creating a winforms application using IronPython.

I'm wondering how I can get a 'next' button to change the image in a PictureBox to the next image in a list.

The application pops up fine, but the next button doesn't change the image. 
It does however print the new value of index every time the 'Next' Button is clicked, for testing purposes.

Here is part of my code:

```
Images = [list, of, images]
index = 0
class IForm(Form):

    def __init__(self):

        self.Text = 'PictureBox'
        pb = PictureBox()
        pb.Parent = self
        pb.Size = Size(1200, 700)
        pb.Location = Point(2, 2)
        pb.Image = Image.FromFile(Images[index]) #should change the image when index is changed

        Next = Button()
        Next.Parent = self
        Next.Text = "Next >"
        Next.Location = Point(1125, 905)
        Next.Click += self.OnNext

        self.Size = Size(1220, 970)
        self.CenterToScreen()

    def OnNext(self, sender, event):  
        global index
        index += 1
        print index

Application.Run(IForm())
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are having is that `pb.Image = Image.FromFile(Images[index]` is not evaluated again automatically, just because the value of `index` changed. You have to do this manually. In your case a simple solution could look like this

```
Images = [list, of, images]
class IForm(Form):

    def __init__(self):
        self.index = 0
        self.Text = 'PictureBox'
        self.pb = PictureBox()
        self.pb.Parent = self
        self.pb.Size = Size(1200, 700)
        self.pb.Location = Point(2, 2)
        self.pb.Image = Image.FromFile(Images[self.index]) 

        Next = Button()
        Next.Parent = self
        Next.Text = "Next >"
        Next.Location = Point(1125, 905)
        Next.Click += self.OnNext

        self.Size = Size(1220, 970)
        self.CenterToScreen()

    def OnNext(self, sender, event): 
        self.index += 1
        # update the image of the PictureBox
        self.pb.Image = Image.FromFile(Images[self.index])
        print self.index

Application.Run(IForm())
```

Note that I made `pb` and `index` member variables of the class here. `pb` because it needs to be accessible in `OnNext` and `index` because you should generally be avoiding `global` variables as much as possible.

In more complex situations, e.g.: when `index` can be changed in different ways than just the button click, you may want to look into changing it into a `property` and have the code for changing the image in the setter method. There are also other alternative approaches, such as creating a `OnValueChanged` callback

Comment: Brill thanks! I'll look into the alternative methods you've mentioned.